# jq with curl fails if select filter is used

Tags: curl, jq

I'm piping curl output to jq: https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ and everything works great until I try to use a select filter.

This very filter works fine when in their online tool: https://jqplay.org/ and in my command line experiments after having downloaded the file.

This issue occurs only when I try to directly pipe the curl output into jq.

This fails:

```
i71178@SLCITS-L2222:~/next-gen/mongodb$ curl 'http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu3/Patient?_format=json&_count=50&_pretty=false&_summary=data' | jq-linux64 --unbuffered -r -c '.link[] | select(.relation == next) | .url' | head -3
jq: error: next/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.link[] | select(.relation == next) | .url                              
jq: 1 compile error
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100  2421    0  2421    0     0   2413      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  2413
curl: (23) Failed writing body (1675 != 2736)
i71178@SLCITS-L2222:~/next-gen/mongodb$
```

This works fine:

```
i71178@SLCITS-L2222:~/next-gen/mongodb$ curl 'http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu3/Patient?_format=json&_count=50&_pretty=false&_summary=data' | jq-linux64 --unbuffered -r -c '.link[] | .url' | head -3  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 46801    0 46801    0     0  66256      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 66290
http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu3/Patient?_count=50&_format=json&_pretty=false&_summary=data
http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu3?_getpages=e73ba3b4-cc7e-4028-8679-b5da1f9cbdd1&_getpagesoffset=50&_count=50&_format=json&_bundletype=searchset
i71178@SLCITS-L2222:~/next-gen/mongodb$
```

For context, this is the what is being pipes into the select filter:

```
i71178@SLCITS-L2222:~/next-gen/mongodb$ curl 'http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu3/Patient?_format=json&_count=50&_pretty=false&_summary=data' | jq-linux64 --unbuffered -r -c '.link[]' | head -3
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 46801    0 46801    0     0  64411      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 64375
{"relation":"self","url":"http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu3/Patient?_count=50&_format=json&_pretty=false&_summary=data"}
{"relation":"next","url":"http://fhirtest.uhn.ca/baseDstu3?_getpages=00952912-c9ab-47ca-826c-200bddffe617&_getpagesoffset=50&_count=50&_format=json&_bundletype=searchset"}
i71178@SLCITS-L2222:~/next-gen/mongodb$
```

I would really appreciate any help here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is evidently your `select` filter:

```
 select(.relation == next)
```

I think you meant:

```
select(.relation == "next")
```

Safer would be:

```
select(.relation? == "next")
```

Comment: Actually, that's what I had initially, I'm pretty sure. I seemed to have mistakenly posted one of my attempts to get it to work. I'll double check and make an edit.

Comment: Looks like it was my copy paste mistake. I was indeed trying to do select(.relation == next) on the command line and that understandably has resulted in an error.

Sorry for the false alarm.